# TextMate TODO not working properly

Tags: textmate

I love using the TODO list in TextMate but I've been having issues of it not finding or not listing the todo's within a project. If I close a project and re-open the project and pull up the todo list using ctrl+shift+t the list shows up properly. Now if I click on one of the links to a todo in a file, it'll take me to the file and line where the todo is. From here if I view the TODO list again nothing on the list shows up until I close the project and re-open it again. I just used svn to reload the Support folder but it's still not working.

Has anyone else had this issue or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually I did figure it out and I forgot to post it here.

It depends on what folder/file is selected in the file drawer. For example if you have the folder (at the top of the file list) that contains all the files selected and then run the TODO list everything shows up cause it's searching that whole folder. If you have one file selected it'll search just that file for the TODOs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is really annoying, because to make use of that, you have to go back one folder, outside your project folder, at least this is what happens with Textmate 2.0